# Simple DOS command-line to ignore data on a line after the last backslash

Tags: command-line, dos

I'm creating a batch file to make multiple directories from a list in a text file
however after the directory is listed sometimes a filename is as well.  Is there an easy way to have it ignore all data after the last \ on a line?

Answer (score 4):

I might suggest that DOS batch isn't the right tool for this job, because it doesn't have built-in facilities for string manipulation like this would need.

If you have Perl available, you can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while (<>) {
    s/\\[^\\]*$//; # this removes a the last backslash and anything after it
    mkdir $_;
}
```

Comment: This post's example is clearly set up for a *nix environment, so it might be worth noting that you can get Perl for Windows and it's very easy to set up.  Just go to the perl site.

Comment: This is great, is there something similar in php?

Comment: Yes, you can do similar things in PHP but since I don't really know PHP I wouldn't be able to give a good example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
@echo off
set filename="c:\temp\my files\file.txt"
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ("%filename%") do set filename="%~dpi"
echo %filename%
```

The result will be `"c:\temp\my files\"`.

Comment: +1: Answered the question asked!

You can find "Help" for the `for' command in "Start|Help", then search for "command-line reference A-Z", click on 'F' and scroll to 'for'

The `connamd-line reference' topic is only available through Search or the Index.